# Java Double checked locking - initialization method

Tags: java, multithreading, double-checked-locking

Consider the example:

```
class SomeClass{
     private Foo val;

     String getVal(){
           if(val == null){
                synchronized(this){
                      if(val ==null)
                           val = generateFoo();
                }
          }
     }

     Foo generateFoo(){
          //some code
          return new Foo();
     }
}
```

Is volatile in this case necessary?

Answer (score 0):

According to [The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) it would appear that making it volatile is required.

> JDK5 and later extends the semantics for volatile so that the system will not allow a write of a volatile to be reordered with respect to any previous read or write, and a read of a volatile cannot be reordered with respect to any following read or write. See this entry in Jeremy Manson's blog for more details.
>
> With this change, the Double-Checked Locking idiom can be made to work by declaring the helper field to be volatile. This does not work under JDK4 and earlier.

However can I make a different suggestion?

Don't use [singletons-the-design-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Make it clear in the API that it should be a singleton. Allow users of your class to use it as a singleton, but to do so in way that makes sense for then, such as using [Singleton-as-a-scope](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes) or in a [Service Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern).

It will be easier to test, easier to work with and it will mean that the goddess who kills a kills kittens every time a singleton is used will not have to kill a kitten. Everyone is happy.

Answer (score 0):

no not necessary.
You can go for AtomicReference.

AtomicReference atomicStringReference =
    new AtomicReference(val);

Check here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html